# Python tkinter - pack append vs pack separate from root

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

Am new to python and tkinter. Trying to write a simple python code to get the username and print it

So, I tried the below

```
root = Tk() # line 1
e = Entry(root, width = 50).pack() # line 2 option 1 - results in below error as shown below
e = Entry(root, width = 50) # line 2 option 2 - works fine
e.pack() # line 3 option 2 - works fine
def clicking():
    word = "Hello " + e.get()
    myLabel = Label(root,text=word).pack()
myButton = Button(root, text = "Generate", command = clicking).pack()
```

When I click on `Generate` button, I expect to see an output like "Hello John"

But I get the below error when I write the line 2 as shown in line 2 option 1 above

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\test~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8876/988003047.py", line 4, in clicking
    word = "Hello " + e.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

However, when I write the line 2 as two separate lines as shown in line 2 option 2 and line 3 option 2, it works fine and I get the below output.

[image]

Can help me understand why does this happen? what is the difference between packing together with root and not with root?

Comment: first: if you use `variable = Widget().pack()` then you assign `None` to variable because `pack()`, `grid()`, `place()` return `None`. And this is the problem. You should do it in two lines `variable = Widget()` and `variable.pack()`

Comment: I am unable to delete this question as it has already been answered. Anyway, similar question can be found here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use

```
variable = Widget().pack()
```

then you assign `None` to `variable` because `pack()`, `grid()`, `place()` return `None`.

You should do it in two lines

```
variable = Widget() 
variable.pack()
```

First line assigns widget to `variable`.
In second line you use `variable` to access this widget.